# iOS - How to display data from plist when there is more than one key?

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I am able to get data from plist but it seems my cellForRowAtIndexPath is not getting called as none of NSLog printing anything from inside the method.

here is my code :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drinks" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.drinks = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Root"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.drinks);
    NSLog(@"Number = %d", self.drinks.count);    
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSLog(@"I am inside cellForRowAtIndexPath");
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.
NSArray *allValues = [self.drinks valueForKey:@"name"];    
NSLog(@"%d", allValues.count);
cell.textLabel.text = [allValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

Here is my console output :-

```
2011-10-01 20:27:01.940 DrinkMixer[1832:b303] (
        {
        directions = "Shake adahsdk adlkasd";
        ingredients = "kslkds lkjsjlkd kjsljlakj aajdlkj";
        name = "Fire Cracker";
    },
        {
        directions = "abds fedfsdkkjkljlkj;j ok";
        ingredients = "hasdhalsdlash asdhasldh kjdfkjshdj";
        name = "Lemon Drop";
    },
        {
        directions = "abds fedfsdkkjkljlkj;j ok";
        ingredients = "hasdhalsdlash asdhasldh kjdfkjshdj";
        name = Mojito;
    },
        {
        directions = "abds fedfsdkkjkljlkj;j ok";
        ingredients = "hasdhalsdlash asdhasldh kjdfkjshdj";
        name = "After Drink Mint";
    },
        {
        directions = "abds fedfsdkkjkljlkj;j ok";
        ingredients = "hasdhalsdlash asdhasldh kjdfkjshdj";
        name = "Apple Martini";
    },
        {
        directions = "abds fedfsdkkjkljlkj;j ok";
        ingredients = "hasdhalsdlash asdhasldh kjdfkjshdj";
        name = "Shockwave";
    },
        {
        directions = "abds fedfsdkkjkljlkj;j ok";
        ingredients = "hasdhalsdlash asdhasldh kjdfkjshdj";
        name = "Beer";
    },
        {
        directions = "abds fedfsdkkjkljlkj;j ok";
        ingredients = "hasdhalsdlash asdhasldh kjdfkjshdj";
        name = "Last Desire";
    },
        {
        directions = "abds fedfsdkkjkljlkj;j ok";
        ingredients = "hasdhalsdlash asdhasldh kjdfkjshdj";
        name = "Vodka";
    }
)
2011-10-01 20:27:01.942 DrinkMixer[1832:b303] Number = 9
```

None of cellForRowAtIndexPath's NSLog get called.

Can anyone please tell what is wrong with this code.

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, so your error must lie somewhere else. Are any of your tableView methods being called? How many rows are being returned, for example?

Comment: I have solved the issue. I did a very silly mistake. I was returning the wrong value from method numberOfRowsInSection. Thanks for trying to help me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are that you either have not implemented `UITableViewDelegate` in your header file, or your `UITableView`'s `datasource` and `delegate` are not wired up in your nib file.

I suggest checking out the `datasource`.

**UPDATE:**

The fact that the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` isn't being called and the `datasource` is set correctly then it could be that the plist is loaded into `self.drinks` after the `UITableView` is already loaded. Proof could be to scroll the empty `UITableView` up and down and see if cells from off the screen start to appear.

I suggest two things:

1. call `[super viewDidLoad];` at the beginning of your `-(void)viewDidLoad`
2. call for a reload your UITableView after the plist is loaded.

Try:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drinks" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.drinks = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Root"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.drinks);
    NSLog(@"Number = %d", self.drinks.count);    

    [yourTableView reload];

}
```

Lastly, the reason I worry about your `datasource` is because I think even an empty cell should call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Hope this helps.

Comment: everything is at right place. This code was working before but i made few changes to my plist and after that it just stopped working although i am still able to fetch data from plist as you can see the console trace. I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Finally i have solved the issue. What a silly mistake. Damn me!! I was returning a wrong value from numberOfRowsInSection. Thanks for trying to help me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it figured out.